# MySQL sum based on col value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | fruit  | a-b-c |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  | orange | a     |
+----+--------+-------+
| 2  | banana | c     |
+----+--------+-------+
| 3  | orange | c     |
+----+--------+-------+
| 4  | orange | a     |
+----+--------+-------+
| 5  | orange | b     |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Now I want to list all the fruits and a `sum` based on the `a-b-c` values.`a=1`, `b=2` and `c=3`. So, this would be the result I want:

```
+--------+-----+
| fruit  | sum |
+--------+-----+
| banana | 3   |
+--------+-----+
| orange | 7   |
+--------+-----+
```

I'm fairly sure that I should use `case`, but I have no idea how to sum them. I have something like this in my mind:

```
SELECT
    fruit,
    sum(a-b-c)
    CASE
        WHEN a-b-c = 'a' THEN +=1
        ELSE
    CASE
        WHEN a-b-c= 'b' THEN +=2
        ELSE
    CASE
        WHEN a-b-c= 'c' THEN +=3

    END AS sum

FROM tbl_fruits
GROUP BY fruit;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT fruit, SUM(CASE `a-b-c`
                     WHEN 'a' THEN 1
                     WHEN 'b' THEN 2
                     WHEN 'c' THEN 3
                  END) AS total 
FROM tbl_fruits
GROUP BY fruit;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a2067/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════╗
║ fruit   ║ total ║
╠═════════╬═══════╣
║ banana  ║     3 ║
║ orange  ║     7 ║
╚═════════╩═══════╝
```

---

Alternatively using `ELT/FIELD`:

```
SELECT fruit, SUM(ELT(FIELD(`a-b-c`,'a','b','c'),1,2,3)) AS total 
FROM tbl_fruits
GROUP BY fruit;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a2067/2/0)**</kbd>