# MYSQL sum based on another table

Tags: mysql, join, sum

assuming i have this two tables,

table A

```
+----------+---------------------------------+
| product  | categories                      |
+----------+---------------------------------+
| vegetable| carrots, cabbage, string beans  |
+----------+---------------------------------+
| fruit    | apple, oranges                  |
+----------+---------------------------------+
```

table B

```
+--------------+----+
|category      |sale|
+--------------+----+
| carrots      | 10 |
+--------------+----+
| cabbage      | 5  |
+--------------+----+
| apple        | 11 |
+--------------+----+
| string beans | 5  |
+--------------+----+
| oranges      | 7  |
+--------------+----+
```

my goal is to get the total amount of sale per product.

```
+----------+----+
| product  |sale|
+----------+----+
| vegetable| 20 |
+----------+----+
| fruit    | 18 |
+----------+----+
```

i thought it was similar to
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976495/mysql-sum-based-on-col-value)
but i think its applies differently to my question,

Comment: Normalize the table `tableA`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has already been mentioned, you should probably avoid storing your inventory as CSV data in the table.  If you must proceed, you can try joining using MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.  This function can search a CSV string for a particular term, and return the index, if found, otherwise zero.

```
SELECT
    a.product,
    SUM(b.sale) AS sale
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
    ON FIND_IN_SET(b.category, REPLACE(a.categories, ', ', ',')) > 0
GROUP BY a.product
ORDER BY SUM(b.sale) DESC;
```

**Notes:**

`FIND_IN_SET()` doesn't take any whitespace you might have in the CSV string into account.  This must also be matched.  Hence, I removed the whitespace in your CSV string before matching to it.  This can get tricky when you also have terms like `string beans` which themselves have whitespace, because we can't do a blanket replacement.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: find in set, I'm new with this. thanks. Will accept as answer when i produced a successful query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.product,SUM(B.SALE) FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON FIND_IN_SET(B.category, REPLACE(A.categories, ', ', ',')) > 0
GROUP BY A.product
```

**OR**

Assuming categories always containing single word category.

```
 SELECT A.product,SUM(B.SALE) FROM TABLEA A
    INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON FIND_IN_SET(B.category, REPLACE(A.categories, ' ', '')) > 0
    GROUP BY A.product
```

Try above code.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Hi Sagar, this was also my initial answer but there is a problem because the CSV strings in the OP's table have whitespace.  To get `FIND_IN_SET()` to behave properly, you will either have to also match that whitespace, or somehow remove it first.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes got it.